# I get an error when I use boost.js file in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

When I use boost js, I got this error on browser:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined

What could be the cause of this problem?

When I inspect element in console I found the error in this `doc = win.document,` and I am using [this](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/js/modules/boost.src.js) for boost.js

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I have included the scripts as follows

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/highstock/2.1.8/highstock.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/highstock/2.1.8/modules/exporting.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/Highcharts/js/modules/boost.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here is my SVG code:

```
/*
  Create a global getSVG method that takes an array of charts as an argument
*/
$(window).load(

    $(function () {
        Highcharts.getSVG = function (charts) {
            var svgArr = [],
                top = 0,
                width = 0;

            $.each(charts, function (i, chart) {
                var svg = chart.getSVG();
                svg = svg.replace('<svg', '<g transform="translate(0,' + top + ')" ');
                svg = svg.replace('</svg>', '</g>');

                top += chart.chartHeight;
                width = Math.max(width, chart.chartWidth);

                svgArr.push(svg);
            });

            return '<svg height="' + top + '" width="' + width + '" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' + svgArr.join('') + '</svg>';
        };

        /**
         * Create a global exportCharts method that takes an array of charts as an argument,
         * and exporting options as the second argument
         */
        Highcharts.exportCharts = function (charts, options) {

            // Merge the options
            options = Highcharts.merge(Highcharts.getOptions().exporting, options);

            // Post to export server
            Highcharts.post(options.url, {
                filename: options.filename || 'chart',
                type: options.type,
                width: options.width,
                svg: Highcharts.getSVG(charts)
            });
        };
```

After that I have set up number of arrays for data coming from controller like this:

```
var myArrayX_kwh = [];
        var myArrayY_kwh = [];
        var myArrayY_power = [];
        var myArrayY_voltage_1 = [];
        var myArrayY_voltage_2 = [];
        var myArrayY_voltage_3 = [];
        var myArrayY_current_1 = [];
        var myArrayY_current_2 = [];
        var myArrayY_current_3 = [];

        var arry_kwh = [];
        var arry_power = [];
        var arry_voltage_1 = [];
        var arry_voltage_2 = [];
        var arry_voltage_3 = [];
        var arry_current_1 = [];
        var arry_current_2 = [];
        var arry_current_3 = [];
```

Now I have added one foreach and one for loop that will push the data into array

```
 @foreach (var st in ViewData["Meter_datetime"] as List<double?>)
        {
        @:myArrayX_kwh.push(@st);
                }

        @foreach (var st in ViewData["energy_kwh"] as List<double?>)
    {
        @:myArrayY_kwh.push(@st);
                }
        @foreach (var st in ViewData["power_kw"] as List<double?>)
    {
        @:myArrayY_power.push(@st);
                }
        @foreach (var st in ViewData["voltage_1"] as List<double?>)
    {
        @:myArrayY_voltage_1.push(@st);
                }
        @foreach (var st in ViewData["voltage_2"] as List<double?>)
    {
        @:myArrayY_voltage_2.push(@st);
                }
        @foreach (var st in ViewData["voltage_3"] as List<double?>)
    {
        @:myArrayY_voltage_3.push(@st);
                }
        @foreach (var st in ViewData["current_1"] as List<double?>)
    {
        @:myArrayY_current_1.push(@st);
                }
        @foreach (var st in ViewData["current_2"] as List<double?>)
    {
        @:myArrayY_current_2.push(@st);
                } @foreach (var st in ViewData["current_3"] as List<double?>)
     {
      @:myArrayY_current_3.push(@st);
                }


        for (var i = 0; i < myArrayX_kwh.length; i++) {
            arry_kwh.push({ x: myArrayX_kwh[i], y: myArrayY_kwh[i], });
            arry_power.push({ x: myArrayX_kwh[i], y: myArrayY_power[i], });
            arry_voltage_1.push({ x: myArrayX_kwh[i], y: myArrayY_voltage_1[i], });
            arry_voltage_2.push({ x: myArrayX_kwh[i], y: myArrayY_voltage_2[i], });
            arry_voltage_3.push({ x: myArrayX_kwh[i], y: myArrayY_voltage_3[i], });
            arry_current_1.push({ x: myArrayX_kwh[i], y: myArrayY_current_1[i], });
            arry_current_2.push({ x: myArrayX_kwh[i], y: myArrayY_current_2[i], });
            arry_current_3.push({ x: myArrayX_kwh[i], y: myArrayY_current_3[i], });
        }
```

after that i have initialized charts as follows

```
var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({

            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container1',
                type: 'column',
                zoomType: 'xy',
                panning: true,
                pankey:'shift',
                resetZoomButton: {
                    position: {
                        //align: 'right', // by default
                        //verticalAlign: 'top', // by default
                        x: -250,
                        y: 5,
                        //height: 25
                    },

                    relativeTo: 'chart'
                }
            },
            navigator: { enabled: true },
            //scrollbar: {
            //    enabled: true,
            //    barBackgroundColor: 'silver',
            //    barBorderRadius: 7,
            //    barBorderWidth: 0,
            //    buttonBackgroundColor: 'silver',
            //    buttonBorderWidth: 0,
            //    buttonArrowColor:'yellow',
            //    buttonBorderRadius: 7,
            //    rilfeColor:'yellow',
            //    trackBackgroundColor: 'none',
            //    trackBorderWidth: 1,
            //    trackBorderRadius: 8,
            //    trackBorderColor: '#CCC'
            //},
            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 4
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    turboThreshold: 2200
                }

            },
            title: {
                text: 'Energy vs Date & Time',
                style: {
                    //color: '#FF00FF',
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    //fontSize: '12px'
                    //sfont: 'bold 200px Verdana, sans-serif',
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                //  categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
                type: 'datetime',
                // max: new Date().getTime(),
                //labels: {

                // //   format: {value:}
                //    style: {
                //        fontSize: '13px',
                //        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                //    }
                //}
            }, yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Energy (kWh)',
                    style: {
                        //color: '#FF00FF',
                        fontSize: '12px',
                        //sfont: 'bold 200px Verdana, sans-serif',
                    }
                }

            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Energy kWh',
                color: 'green',
                data: arry_kwh,
            }]


        });
```

I have 2 line charts and 2 bar charts and I have done the same initialization as done with chart1

```
var chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart({.........});
```

Comment: show me the code so we can see where is the problem

Comment: the js code is in the link i have copied the same

Comment: We would like to see how you are using your code, because using boost.js should not cause this problem. Have you seen an examples of using boost.js? How you are loading your scripts? Is highcharts.js script before boost.js?

Comment: see the updated code

Comment: I still need help